# How to block Gnome Popup Notifications for Mounted Media?

Tags: gnome

When ever I mount something, when ever I plug in a USB, gnome pops up. Its annoying. Isn't there a way to stop this? I saw some people suggest disabling the autorun. But I want to completely stop! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steal My Focus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/234/steal-my-focus/) is an extension for GNOME which solves the exact problem you have. You can easily activate the extension right from your web browser.